# Dart: What is the proper way to sum up items in a list of Maps?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, dart

I am trying to figure out what is the best way to sum up all the same item's quantities specifically the data is formed like below:

```
data = [
          {Item Name: Item 2, Quantity: 1}, 
          {Item Name: Item 1, Quantity: 1}, 
          {Item Name: Item 3, Quantity: 1}, 
          {Item Name: Item 2, Quantity: 2}, 
          {Item Name: Item 1, Quantity: 2}, 
          {Item Name: Item 3, Quantity: 2},
       ];
```

and what I am trying to achieve is:

```
totalList = [{Item Name: Item 1, Quantity: 3}, {Item Name: Item 2, Quantity: 3}, {Item Name: Item 3, Quantity: 3}];
```

I have tried using a **tempData** variable to hold onto the element and compare the rest however, this seems like it only compares that first one to the rest of the list.

```
var tempData = {};
var totalList = [];
data.forEach((element) {
  if (tempData.isEmpty) {
    tempData = element;
    totalList.add(tempData);
  } else {
    if (tempData['Item Name'] == element['Item Name']) {
       tempData['Quantity'] = tempData['Quantity'] + element['Quantity'];
       totalList.add(tempData);
      } else {
        tempData = {
         'Item Name': element['Item Name'],
         'Quantity': element['Quantity']
     };
      totalList.add(tempData);
   }
  }
});
```

The above didnt seem to give me the output I was looking for...

What should I do instead?

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: What output is it giving you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data structure is not pretty; the `'Item Name'` and `'Quantity'` labels not very useful in the structure itself, so I would get rid of them and create a simplified `Map<String, int>` that directly maps names to quantities. Ideally you could just use the simplified structure from then on, but if you really need the explicit labels, you could convert back.

```dart
void main(List<String> args) async {
  var data = [
    {'Item Name': 'Item 2', 'Quantity': 1},
    {'Item Name': 'Item 1', 'Quantity': 1},
    {'Item Name': 'Item 3', 'Quantity': 1},
    {'Item Name': 'Item 2', 'Quantity': 2},
    {'Item Name': 'Item 1', 'Quantity': 2},
    {'Item Name': 'Item 3', 'Quantity': 2},
  ];

  // Sum everything into a simpler data structure.
  var totalCounts = <String, int>{};
  for (var map in data) {
    var name = map['Item Name'] as String;
    var quantity = map['Quantity'] as int;
    totalCounts[name] = (totalCounts[name] ?? 0) + quantity;
  }

  // Reformat back into the original structure.
  var totalList = <Map<String, dynamic>>[
    for (var entry in totalCounts.entries)
      {'Item Name': entry.key, 'Quantity': entry.value},
  ];
  
  // Optional: Sort.
  totalList.sort((a, b) => a['Item Name'].compareTo(b['Item Name']));

  print(totalList); // Prints: [{Item Name: Item 1, Quantity: 3}, {Item Name: Item 2, Quantity: 3}, {Item Name: Item 3, Quantity: 3}]
}
```

In real code, I additionally would add:

```dart
const nameLabel = 'Item Name';
const quantityLabel = 'Quantity';
```

and use those everywhere instead of the string literals to reduce opportunities for making typos.

Answer (score 0):

I have created the following solution which are not that pretty but it works. The concept is to create a `Map<String, Map<String, Object>>` which keep track of elements we already have visited by using the "Item Name" of each element as key.

```
void main() {
  final data = [
    {'Item Name': 'Item 2', 'Quantity': 1},
    {'Item Name': 'Item 1', 'Quantity': 1},
    {'Item Name': 'Item 3', 'Quantity': 1},
    {'Item Name': 'Item 2', 'Quantity': 2},
    {'Item Name': 'Item 1', 'Quantity': 2},
    {'Item Name': 'Item 3', 'Quantity': 2},
  ];

  final result = [
    ...data.fold(
        <String, Map<String, Object>>{},
        (Map<String, Map<String, Object>> sum, element) => sum
          ..update(
              element['Item Name'] as String,
              (value) => value
                ..update('Quantity',
                    (value) => (value as int) + (element['Quantity'] as int)),
              ifAbsent: () => Map.from(element))).values
  ];

  result.sort(
      (a, b) => (a['Item Name'] as String).compareTo(b['Item Name'] as String));

  print(result); // [{Item Name: Item 1, Quantity: 3}, {Item Name: Item 2, Quantity: 3}, {Item Name: Item 3, Quantity: 3}]
}
```